# I have no data with joined ad_categories table

Tags: laravel

In laravel 8 I make request with condition on joined ad_categories table :

```
$adsCategories = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8];

$data = Ad
    ::whereDate('expire_date', '>=', $date_start)
    ->whereDate('expire_date', '<', $date_end)
    ->orderBy($order_by, $order_direction)
    ->with('adCategories')
    ->with('creator')
    ->withCount('adLocations')
    ->leftJoin('ad_categories', 'ad_categories.ad_id', '=', 'ads.id')
    ->whereIn('ad_categories.category_id', $adsCategories)
    ->get();
```

and tracing sql :

```
   SELECT `ads`.*, (  SELECT count(*) 
    FROM `ad_locations` 
    WHERE `ads`.`id` = `ad_locations`.`ad_id`)     AS `ad_locations_count` 
    FROM `ads` 
    LEFT JOIN `ad_categories` on `ad_categories`.`ad_id` = `ads`.`id` 
    WHERE date(`expire_date`) >= '2021-04-01'     AND date(`expire_date`) < '2021-05-01'     AND `ad_categories`.`category_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8') 
    ORDER BY `expire_date` asc, `price` desc
```

I got no rows returned, but in database I see ralated rows :

Manually removing rows with ad_categories`.`category_id` :

```
   SELECT `ads`.*, (  SELECT count(*) 
    FROM `ad_locations` 
    WHERE `ads`.`id` = `ad_locations`.`ad_id`)     AS `ad_locations_count` 
    FROM `ads` 
    LEFT JOIN `ad_categories` on `ad_categories`.`ad_id` = `ads`.`id` 
    WHERE date(`expire_date`) >= '2021-04-01'     AND date(`expire_date`) < '2021-05-01'   
    ORDER BY `expire_date` asc, `price` desc
```

I got all data I need.

What is wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use select...

```
$data = Ad
    ::whereDate('expire_date', '>=', $date_start)
    ->whereDate('expire_date', '<', $date_end)
    ->orderBy($order_by, $order_direction)
    ->with('adCategories')
    ->with('creator')
    ->withCount('adLocations')
    ->leftJoin('ad_categories', 'ad_categories.ad_id', '=', 'ads.id')
    ->whereIn('ad_categories.category_id', $adsCategories)
    ->select('ads.*', 'ad_categories.*') // <- add this line of code
    ->get();
```